# Java Programming Debug Quiz

Tags: java

This quiz is in two parts. First is

```
public class FixDebugBox {
   private int width;
   private int length;
   private int height;
     private double Volume;

   public void FixDebugbox() {
     length = 1;
     width = 1;
     height = 1;
   }
   public FixDebugBox(int width, int length, int height) {
      width = width;
      length = length;
      height = height;
   }
   public void showData() {
     System.out.println("Width: "  + width + "  Length: " +
      length + "  Height: " + height);
   }
   public double getVolume() { 
     double vol = length * width * height;
         return Volume;
   }
}
```

The code above is one half of the quiz, it have the code above complied correctly but the second part I can't

```
public class FixDebugFour3
// This class uses a FixDebugBox class to instantiate two Box objects
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int width = 12;
      int length = 10;
      int height = 8;

      FixDebugBox box1 = new FixDebugBox(width, length, height);
      FixDebugBox box2 = new FixDebugBox(width, length, height);
      System.out.println("The dimensions of the first box are");
      box1.showData();
      System.out.println("The volume of the first box is");
      showVolume(box1);
      System.out.println("The dimensions of the first box are");
      box2.showData();
      System.out.println("The volume of the second box is");
      showVolume(box2);
   }
   public void showVolume() {
      double vol = FixDebugBox.getVolume();
      System.out.println(vol);
   }

}
```

I keep getting an error with double vol = FixDebugBox.getVolume(); error: non-static method getVolume() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: If this is a quiz then what is the prize?

Comment: If this is a quiz, what's the question?

Comment: What is the timeline to submit the homework?

Comment: You're doing `showVolume(box1)` but `showVolume()` doesn't take a box (hint: it should).

Answer (score 0):

```
FixDebugBox.getVolume();
```

`getVolume` is non static method you can not call this with class name, its a public method which you need object to call it.

```
   public void showVolume(FixDebugBox box) {
      double vol = box.getVolume();
      System.out.println(vol);
   }
```

**Now give me the prize.** :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you already answered yourself. You need to hold a reference to an instance of `FixDebugBox` in order to call its non-static methods.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you can't call a non-static method from the static context that is the main method. While you could turn your `showVolume()` to be a static method and take a `FixDebugBox` instance as an argument, seeing how `FixDebugBox` objects already have a `getVolume()` method, just call it for each instance:

```
System.out.println(box1.getVolume());
...
System.out.println(box2.getVolume());
```

Also, don't change the name of your `Volume` variable to `volume`. You should use camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

If you move

```
public void showVolume() {
  double vol = FixDebugBox.getVolume();
  System.out.println(vol);
}
```

to the `class FixDebugBox` 
and remove the `getVolume()` method in`class FixDebugBox` , and change the `showVolume()` method to:

```
public void showVolume() {
    double vol = length * width * height;
    Volume = vol;
    System.out.println(Volume);
}
```

That would fix your program. Also `boxVolume` would be a better name instead of `Volume`, since variables are not supposed to be written with a capital letter.